# Display & Video 360 API - while uploading asset getting error Invalid Upload Request. Please check your URL and ensure it includes the /upload prefix

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, dv360

[image: Graph API Error]

I am using https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v2/advertisers.assets/upload  - **Method: advertisers.assets.upload**

But while uploading asset getting error - **Invalid Upload Request. Please check your URL and ensure it includes the /upload prefix**

Comment: The first item I notice is that `Content-type` is wrong. Images are not JSON. Next, I would not add the `--compressed` flag.

Comment: I am using Google Graph API Explorer, and there is no option to change these values.

Comment: Then use a tool that does allow you to set the correct values. For example, use the CLI `curl`, which your screenshot shows an example.